# Performance drop when getting attributes of files residing on an SMB mount

Tags: winapi, smb

I have a piece of code in C++ that lists files in a folder and then gets attributes for each of them through Windows API. I am puzzled by the performance of this code when the folder is an SMB mount on a remote server (mounted as a disk).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>

//#include <chrono>
//#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFile;

    std::string pathStr = argv[1];
    std::vector<std::string> paths;

    hFile = FindFirstFile((pathStr + "\\*").c_str(), &ffd);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "FindFirstFile failed: " << GetLastError();
        return 1;
    } else {
        do {
            paths.push_back(pathStr + "\\" + ffd.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFile, &ffd) != 0);

        int error = GetLastError();
        if (error != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            std::cout << "FindNextFile failed: " << error;
            FindClose(hFile);
            return error;
        }
        FindClose(hFile);
    }

    std::cout << paths.size() << " files listed" << std::endl;

    // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30000));
    
    for (const std::string & p : paths) {
        int a = GetFileAttributes(p.c_str());
        bool isDir = (a & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY);
        bool isHidden = (a & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
        std::cout << p << ": " << (isDir ? "D" : "f") << (isHidden ? "H" : "_") << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Namely, if I have a folder with 250 files, it passes in about 1 second. When there are 500 files, it passes in about 1 minute, and even the first files take hundreds of milliseconds each (so, 1 second is enough for ~10 files).
Experimenting with it, I found that there is some limit below which processing speed is in hundreds files per second and above which the speed is ~10 files per second. I also noticed that this number differs with file name length. With names like `file-001`: between 510 and 520. With names like `file-file-file-file-file-001`: between 370 and 380.

I am interested in why this happens, in particular why the speed degrades from the very beginning when there are "too many" files/folders in the folder. Is there a way to investigate that? Optional: is there a way to overcome that while still using `GetFileAttributes`?

*(The code is probably ugly as hell, I just stuck it together from samples found online. I compile it with MinGW, `g++ -static files.cpp -o files.exe`, run it `files.exe "Z:\test_folder"`.
My original code is in Java, and I got from reading the source of the Hotspot JVM that it uses `GetFileAttributes` WinAPI method, so I created this snippet to see if it would behave the same as the Java code — and it does. I am also limited in the ways to solve this performance problem: I noticed that `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` WinAPI calls perform consistently fast, but I did not find a way to use it from Java without JNI/JNA which would be too much fuss for me.)*

**Update:** if I put a 30-second sleep between listing (files collected into a vector) and getting their attributes in a loop, behavior becomes consistent with any number of files in the folder — "slow" for any number of files. I also read some scattered info here and there that Windows SMB client applies caching, limited by time etc. I guess this is what I see here: listing the folder fills this cache with file attributes, and subsequent `GetFileAttributes` does not hit the remote system if ran immediately after the listing. I guess the other behavior is also cache related: when listing "too many" files, only the tail of the list remains in the cache. Then we start `GetFileAttributes` from the first file again, and every request hits the server. Still a mystery to me why listing is so fast and `GetFileAttributes` is slow...

**Update 2:** I thought to confirm that it has something to do with the cache, but I was not lucky so far. If it had something to do with eviction of the "first" file attributes, then getting attributes in the reverse order would hit the cache for many files — not the case: it's either all fast or all slow.

I tried fiddling with SMB client parameters according to [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/role/file-server/), hoping that if I set sizes really high I won't notice the slow behavior any more — was not the case either, the behavior seems to be completely independent from these parameters. What I set was:

```
// HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
DirectoryCacheEntriesMax = 4096
DirectoryCacheEntrySizeMax = 32768
FileInfoCacheEntriesMax = 8192
```

In addition, I noticed that when there are "too many files", listing returns paths in random order (not alphabetically sorted). Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem. This behavior is even when changing listing to use `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`.

In addition, I studied more carefully the timeout that is needed to "invalidate" the "cache" (so, for a folder with few files to start behaving slowly), and it is around 30 seconds in my case. Sometimes setting a lower value shows the same behavior (slow attributes getting for a folder with few files), but then re-running the program is instantaneous again.

I updated the code above, originally used `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` from C++17.

Comment: Did you look into the `fs::directory_iterator` implementation to find out, what it is doing? That might uncover why it behaves the way it does. Although I'm confused by this question: You seem to be interested in performance, but not nearly enough to implement what you have identified as a solution.

Comment: @IInspectable: thank you for your comment! `fs::directory_iterator` executes instantly: if I first accumulate everything from the iterator in a vector, this takes sub-second time in both cases. The difference comes from `GetFileAttributes`. As to the second part of your comment: for me it's 50% theoretical interest and 50% hope that if I understand why it happens I might be able to overcome it using some approach that is not an overkill for my situation.

Comment: Does this problem occur when used locally? Or just reproduce the problem on the SMB mount of the remote server? Because the performance of the API did not seem to decrease when I tested it locally.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT : Only when files/folders are on a remote mount.

Comment: Try to do the same with `FindFirstFile` instead of `directory_iterator`.

Comment: @i486 : I updated the code snippet to use `FindFirstFile`. The effect is the same (listing now takes somewhat longer, like 3-4 seconds instead of 1).

Comment: @starikoff There is `dwFileAttributes` member in `WIN32_FIND_DATA` - no need to read again with `GetFileAttributes`.

Comment: @i486 Yes, but unfortunately I cannot use it easily: originally, the code is in Java and Java does not expose `dwFileAttributes` through any API. The snippet here was a translation into C++ to exclude the "Java" factor. I was hoping to at least understand the reason for `GetFileAttributes` performance behavior and by this hoped to maybe find some means that would be achievable through standard Java (or an easy workaround, e.g. update some registry parameter etc). Also, just curious what mechanism regulates this behavior.